# Creating a registration and login form with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have coded my registration form with Wordpress following those steps :

1. The code file for connecting to MySQL database is in my template
   editor file (`archive.php`).
2. I changed the template name to php
3. I went back to my registration page editor to change the template to
   the `signup.php` file.
4. I created from my template editor
5. I set my
   form action to `signup.php`

But it doesn't work with the registration page at all, I don't know what else to do.

How can I create a PHP file in WordPress that will be used as my form action.

Please help...

Comment: use wordpress hooks for easy process. check link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register

Comment: Thanks, but the link doesnt help..